# Using predict alongside Naive Bayes. Able to calculate conditional probabilities but produce completely wrong prediction probabilities

Tags: r, probability, naivebayes

I am trying to predict whether or not to play given new data:

```
m <- NaiveBayes(as.factor(play)~ ., data=train)
weather     Temp    humidity    wind    play
fine        hot     high        none    no
fine        hot     high        few     no
cloud       hot     high        none    yes
rain        warm    high        none    yes
rain        cold    medium      none    yes
rain        cold    medium      few     no
cloud       cold    medium      few     yes
fine        warm    high        none    no
fine        cold    medium      none    yes
```

I use this to create the new test instance

```
`> wind <- factor("few",levels(train$wind))
    > Temp <- factor("cold",levels(train$Temp))
    > humidity <- factor("high",levels(train$humidity))
    > weather<- factor("cloud",levels(train$weather))
    test <- data.frame(weather,Temp,humidity,wind)
    predict(m,newdata=test)`
```

This is the output

```
$class
[1] yes
Levels: no yes

$posterior
              no       yes
[1,] 0.004836495 0.9951635
```

I have also tried

```
m <- NaiveBayes(as.factor(train)~ ., data=train.play)
```

But returns the same probabilities

Comment: This `weather<- factor("cold",levels(train$weather))` will be `NA` because "cold" is not a level of the `weather` variable.

Comment: That was a typo sorry

Comment: ok. Can you explain why you think the result is wrong? There is not question in your question.

Comment: Its a relatively simple problem and I have calculated the probabilities by hand and got:
Yes: 0.01067

Comment: You forgot the denominator so what you are giving is actually not a probability. It makes sense only to compare 0.01067 with the numerator you get for No, which here is 0 because you have not observed any "No" under weather "cloud".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Probabilistic_model : in your case you lack the "Z" denominator of the last formula. You do not need to compute it to build a classifier (because this denominator is constant so you need only compare the numerators) but you do need to compute it if you wish to report probabilities.

Comment: If I use new test data where there are no zero instances such as:
> Temp <- factor("cold",levels(train$Temp))
> humidity <- factor("high",levels(train$humidity))
> weather<- factor("fine",levels(train$weather))
> wind <- factor("few",levels(train$wind))

I get from the code:

$posterior
          no     yes
[1,] 0.85363 0.14637
But by hand for no i get 0.02

Comment: For this example I get by hand 0.03125 for no and 0.005333 for yes. Bear in mind that these are not directly probabilities since the scaling factor is lacking. However you can say that a "no" is 0.03125/0.005333 = 5.85 times more likely than a yes. Now, that is all the info you need if you want to express this as a nice yes/no probability such that `P(yes) + P(no) = 1` and  `P(yes) * 5.85 = P(no)`! In practice, you find these values by normalising the vector c(0.03125, 0.005333).

Comment: So just to link back with your R output: `0.03125/(0.03125+0.005333)` is 85.4% and `0.005333/(0.03125+0.005333)` is 14.6%, which is your R output.

Comment: That is great. Thanks Antoine